# How to make a conditional invalidateOptionsMenu() call depending on the API level in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to update the menu buttons of my app every time one of them is pressed; in API 11+, you need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to do this; since I want my app to be compatible with lower APIs, how do I only call this method when using api 11+?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use

```
ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity activity)
```

from the [compatibility library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28android.app.Activity%29).

Comment: How about calling invalidateOptionsMenu() in fragment by using compatibility lib? like this getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();  ?

Comment: It seems this is deprecated now.

Answer (score 44):

For the others who are looking for an answer like I was:

If you are using **ActionBarSherlock** and trying to refresh the action bar buttons on API <11, instead of

[`Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29)

you can use

`SherlockActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`:

Comment: Error: "non-static method supportInvalidateOptionsMenu cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, the notation I used above is just to show it is a method of `SherlockActivity`. You have to use it on an instance of that class, so typically inside your `SherlockActivity` activity you would just use `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` (or `this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`).

Comment: If you're in a Fragment, it will be `getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: The answer of @candrews did not work for me when using ActionBarSherlock, but this one does. Thank you.

Answer (score 30):

If you are extending ActionBarActivity in your class then you just need this:

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: that did it for me. If you use the android.support.v7.app.ActionBar this is the right answer.

Answer (score 7):

I dont think there is any need for compatibility library and so on, just do a simple

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
}
```

You dont need to call it before honeycomb since afaik, onPrepareOptionsMenu() called when menu button is pressed. It works for me.

Comment: This will not build, since both SDK_INT and invalidateOptionsMenu() are from later SDKs.

Comment: well for me it compiles and works just fine and i have minSdk of froyo and targetSdk is ICS

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  It is true that it won't *compile* against a pre-v3 android, but it will run on old versions, just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a FragmentActivity from the [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) instead of a normal activity? I believe the FramentActivity would then have the method that you need.

Comment: Sadly, it does not. It extends `Activity`, so if you are targeting API 11+ you "have" it, but atlas, that's the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think I've got it... the answer was to create a new class:

```
public class wrapThree {
    public void invalidate(myActivity act) {
        act.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

and then call that method from myActivity if the API is 11+

At least this doesn't give errors on API < 11... still have to test it on API 11+

Comment: Maybe you should accept one of the proper answers, I know it's old but people still land here ;).