# Navigation Drawer For Android API-8

Tags: java, android, animation, layout

I'm implementing an app that uses "Side menu" like the FB Application.
The "[Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)" is customized for Applications that runs APIs > 11, and my app is intended to be used by any device, even if API < 11, So, I'm using the `ActionBarSherloc`, and replaced the normal `Menu`, `MenuItem`, and `MenuInflater` with Sherloc equivalents, and extended `SherlocFragmentActivity`.

But for now, i still got an Error inside the "" method :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar()
                    .getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

In the "if-Statment"...

```
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected((android.view.MenuItem) item)) {
            return true;
        }
```

if i used "(android.view.MenuItem) item)"...the method throws an exception for the type, and if i replaced it with "**com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem"...the method still got an Error of "The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) in the type ActionBarDrawerToggle is not applicable for the arguments (MenuItem)**".

Any help..?!
Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think you might want to take a quick look at the official support library that includes the navigation drawer, fragment, and action bar support for APIs < 11. See http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Comment: @MagicMicky I did that, but i still don't know what is the best replacement for "getActionBar()".

Comment: Well, if you are using AppCompat, you need to call getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar() if that's what you want to do.

Comment: @MagicMicky I'm extending "Activity" and calling "getSupportActionBar()"..and got an Error for "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type MainActivity"...do i need to extend something except "android.app.Activity"..?

Comment: Yeap you need to extend ActionBarActivity. And be sure to add appCompat as a dependency in your `build.gradle`. Read this for more information on AppCompat and its actionbar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding

Comment: @MagicMicky what's the suitable replacment of calling "invalidateOptionsMenu" method..?!!, as it's >=API-11.

Comment: `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu` seems to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008470/android-invalidateoptionsmenu-for-api-11

Answer (score 2):

ActionBarSherlock is a wrapper around the compatibility library that Android includes.  You can certainly use ABS, as it simplifies handling of action bars, but it's not necessary for just doing a  NavigationDrawer.

If you have the latest KitKat (sdk 19) look in your `<SDK_HOME>/extras/android/support/v4/` folder there is a `android-support-v4.jar` which contains among other things the appropriate `DrawerLayout`  for doing exactly what you want.  If you include this library in your project you can run it fine.

[This project](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip) demonstrates use of the NavigationDrawer without using ABS.  You will have to make two changes to the Manifest to have it run on API v8.

1. Change the minSdkVersion:  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`
2. Remove the theme:  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the support library, try using getSupportMenuInflater() and getSupportActionBar() instead of the regular methods.