# How to Remove menu button from Android?

Tags: android, menu

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/91fifywlz/Untitled.png]

How I can remove this button? Android API 17.

Comment: Are you targeting API 17? Are you using an ActionBar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar ?

Comment: @Bram that's not the question, actually.

Comment: Targeting API 17, without ActionBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `android:targetSdkVersion` [to 14 or higher](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html). See also [the "Say Goodbye to the Menu Button" post from the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).

Answer (score 2):

remove `@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}`
 and

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {}
```

Comment: That's actually the most straightforward answer to the question :-D

Comment: I tried 

`@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        item.setVisible(false);
        System.out.println("MENU ITEM : DISABLED");
        return true;
    }`

This code is never executed

Comment: you should remove both methods.

Comment: There were no this methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can override these methods, if removing them didn't work for you.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
// do nothing here. Leave it as it is.
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
// do nothing here. 
}
```