# Hide SubMenu and SearchView in the Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to hide both the SubMenu and the SearchView in the ActionBar. I am using ActionBarSherlock.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;         

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Zong ol na...");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);

    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mSuggestionsAdapter);

    SubMenu sub = menu.addSubMenu("Menu");
    sub.add(0, R.style.Theme_Sherlock, 0, "Topic");
    sub.add(0, R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light, 0, "Thuthlunghlui");        
    sub.getItem().setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(isLight ? R.drawable.ic_search_inverse : R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

I want to hide SubMenu and SearchView by clicking the button

```
Btn_Hide_Menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        { //here I want to hide both the SubMenu and SearchView
```

I can't sort it out myself. Is this possible? Excuse me I am being too naive.
[image]

Comment: Here is answer for your question : [hide menu item][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar

Answer (score 1):

Try this Hope it works

```
    Btn_Hide_Menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            { //here I want to hide both the SubMenu and SearchView
                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_item);
                item.setVisible(false);    
            }    
     }
```

Comment: Hi Tanim, thanks for the help. But I'm still confused with MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_item); istead of my_item what should I put here?

Comment: i ve added another ans for you ... take a look please

Answer (score 1):

If you have menu in `menu_main.xml` file like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/tanim"
        android:title="Books"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />    

</menu>
```

declare  some global variable in your activity class

```
private Menu menu;
private MenuItem item;
private MenuItem item1;
```

now look inside your `onOptionCreateMenu()`

```
    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
             item = menu.findItem(R.id.tanim);// hare tanim is menu id comes from xml file..

            menu.add("search"); // this menu add hare no xml id ... so you need the index number of this menu  
            // index is 0=search,1=settings,2=tanim  

            item1=menu.getItem(0);// this is search menu
             return true;
        }
```

and finally your button click event , hare item,item1 is global var..

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.setVisible(false);
                item1.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
```

feel free to ask any question... Thank you