# How to make custom view take up all the actionbar space so it will cover menu as well?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-actionbar

I have created app with similar functionality to a browser. This is what I have right now:

[image: actionbar]

Whenever user clicks on the edittext(the one with google.com inside it) i want to to take all of the space in actionbar covering overflow button and other icons(those are menu items as well).

Is there any way way I could do that? So far I have tried setting the layout-weight of the edittext to 1 but it does not work. The custom view inside actionbar is an linear layout like this one here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/searchfield"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
    android:text="www.google.com" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I should also mention that i want to do it programatically.

Thanks guys

Comment: You could add your own actionbar with blackjack & etc by calling activity's `requestWindowFeature`

Comment: May be you can hide the menu items when the EditText is clicked.

Comment: I found a way of hiding menu items, can you hide whole menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide these icons by following topic: [How do I hide a menu item in the actionbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar)

I think you can easily hide the actionbar when click,
something like:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); //OR getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Then bring it back when you need it by using:

```
actionBar.show();
```

Comment: The problem is that the edittext is inside that actionbar as well. Wouldn't this hide the edittext as well?