# How to hide a menu item in Android using XML (and not code-behind)?

Tags: android, xml, menuitem

I tried `android:visibility="gone"` and `android:visibility="invisible"`.
I also tried `android:enabled="false"`. It will only disable the menu item, but I need to completely hide it (so it should not even show the space allocated for that item).

What changes can I make to the XML so that a menu item can be hidden?

Comment: What does it mean, if you are writing an item that is `invisible`? there is no space, no action, no nothing

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39324927). The correct attribute setting is `android:visible="false"`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    **android:visible="false"**
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

This worked for me.

Comment: For few menu items its above solution is working.But in few menu items its having no effect. I also tried android:visibility="gone"

Comment: What is 'few menu items'? can you add them to your question?