# How to hide drawer icon and menu items in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, toolbar

I am working on **Xamarin Android Application**.  I have three fragments and one of them is a BaseFragment.  I have put Toolbar and Drawerview in base fragment.  Now when I go to next fragment I want to **change menu items and want to hide drawer icon** as well.  How to do that, any idea ?

I have tried `SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`, `SetHomeButtonEnabled(false)` and `SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` to hide drawer icon but it didn't worked.

```
        public abstract class BaseFragment : MvxFragment
{
    private Toolbar _toolbar;
    private MvxActionBarDrawerToggle _drawerToggle;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = this.BindingInflate(FragmentId, null);

        _toolbar = view.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        if (_toolbar != null)
        {
            ((MainActivity)Activity).SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
            ((MainActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

            _drawerToggle = new MvxActionBarDrawerToggle(
                Activity,                               // host Activity
                ((MainActivity)Activity).DrawerLayout,  // DrawerLayout object
                _toolbar,                               // nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret
                Resource.String.drawer_open,            // "open drawer" description
                Resource.String.drawer_close            // "close drawer" description
            );

            ((MainActivity)Activity).DrawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
        }
        return view;
    }

    protected abstract int FragmentId { get; }
```

Comment: Best will be do show what you have.  Are you calling your `set...()` after or before you call to base?

Comment: I am calling that in BaseFragment

Comment: Have a look at this question. Might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765184/how-can-i-refresh-the-actionbar-when-onprepareoptionsmenu-switched-menu-entries

you can invalidate your action bar and then reload the action bar

Comment: didn't get anything from that.