# Android - Refresh Options Menu without calling invalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: java, android, options-menu

Hello Android Developers,

I have seen a lot of question regarding the update of Options Menu. However, every answer says I have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.
My question is, is there any other way of updating the Options Menu without invoking the method `invalidateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `invalidateOptionsMenu()`? That's exactly what it's there for...

Comment: I've created a classA that extends Activity. Created classB that extends classA. classC (Invokes my XML activity) extends classC.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11699930/597657

Comment: Actually, I have created the OptionsMenu, I just have to update the OptionsMenu dynamically.

Comment: I'm still not seeing why that precludes you using `invalidateOptionsMenu()`. @Eng.Fouad has an answer you could use, but I'm still not seeing the problem, I guess.

Comment: Actually, classC doesn't have the method invalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: Plus, calling invalidateOptionsMenu() from superclass of superclass would break the encapsulation. Quoted from Skeet

Comment: Confirming. In my code the menu content is dependent on certain Model states and some of them are triggered in a deferred way through services work result. The logic of "onResults" could became hard to comprehend really quick and will require a lot of synchroniztion efforts. The onPrepareOptionsMenu solution helps to track all of that in a single place without any complications or fluidity impact as far as your menu changes are limited to hide/show/add/remove. Just KISS.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.clear(); // Clear the menu first

            /* Add the menu items */

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

This solved the problem on updating the OptionsMenu without invoking the `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: invalidateOptionsMenu calls onItemSelected of spinner in action bar i have to give a try for this!

Comment: this works! I can't use invalidateOptionsMenu because somehow after calling that, the toast that suppose to show up after long pressing menu item icon does not work anymore

Comment: I cannot see how I could use your solution. Maybe you could help me on a similar problem that I am facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756799/android-studio-invalidateoptionsmenu-causes-the-always-visible-items-to-stop