# how to get another menu item, in onOptionItemSelected

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have menu file like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_select_all"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_select_all"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_deselect_all"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_deselect_all"
    android:visible="false"/>
</menu>
```

and i want to show only one at a time, when i click on one, other show be invisible. can we not get activity's menu by any method of activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133141/android-changing-option-menu-items-programmatically

Comment: set the visibility on menu clicked.

Comment: @CobraAjgar but in public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {........}, we get the item, so how can set other item's visibility ?

Comment: you are making second item invisible in starting...and click on other menu show it..just give it try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

after inflate do this

```
  if (CONDITION) {
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_select_all);
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
                  else
                        {
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_deselect_all);
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
```

Make sure that you call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` when you need to refresh menu

Comment: your method is quite good but that doesn't working because i am showing menu in ActionBar, hence onPrepareOptionsMenu is not called when i click on menu. and also i can't call invalidateOptionsMenu(); as my app's minSdkVirsion=8

Comment: can we check on which android version app is running, in program, then we can make a condition for invalidateOptionsMenu() call

Comment: Yes use android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT for that

Comment: wow great, now i can check for have i to call invalidateOptionsMenu() or not, great. thanks a lot