# how to add new item to setting menu at Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

> i need to add **facebook** like at setting menu as below image .so how to add  new item to setting menu I tried to solve this issue only i had found the setting menu at res > values >string.xml > settings menu .

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<menu>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="About"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_exit"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Exit"/>
```

```
<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"


 <RelativeLayout   


          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <WebView
         android:id="@+id/web_engine"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      </WebView>
```

Comment: Maybe res -> array -> menu ? or res -> menu -> main_activity ?

Comment: maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133141/android-changing-option-menu-items-programmatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open **'/res/menu/menu.xml'**
2. Add this code in it:

   ```
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_about"
       android:orderInCategory="2"
       android:showAsAction="never"
       android:title="About"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_exit"
       android:orderInCategory="3"
       android:showAsAction="never"
       android:title="Exit"/>
   ```
3. Open **'/src/(packagename)/(acitivityname).java'**
4. Add this code there

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     switch (item.getItemId()) {
>     case R.id.action_about:
>         // About option clicked.
>         return true;
>     case R.id.action_exit:
>         // Exit option clicked.
>         return true;
>     case R.id.action_settings:
>         // Settings option clicked.
>         return true;
>     default:
>         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: error displayed the app stopped unfortunately , i had edited the question and added my activity .